# Path.computeBounds returns incorrect boundary on Android (is this platform bug?)

Tags: android, path

When I compute the bounds of a closed path using following two techniques below, I encountered several issues.

**Method 1**

```
    public RectF Truncate(Path path) {

      RectF figureLocationF = new RectF();
      path.computeBounds(figureLocationF, true);
      return   figureLocationF;
    }
```

**Method 2**

```
  public RectF Truncate(Path path) {

    RectF figureLocationF = new RectF();
    path.computeBounds(figureLocationF, true);
    Rect figureLocation = new Rect((int)Math.floor(figureLocationF.left), (int)Math.floor(figureLocationF.top)
    ,(int)Math.ceil(figureLocationF.right), (int)Math.ceil(figureLocationF.bottom));


    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Region region = new Region();
    region.setPath(path, new Region(figureLocation));
    region.getBounds(bounds);

    return new RectF(bounds)
  }
```

The following image shows the results 
[image]

Method 1 returns bounds that are larger than the path, which is confusing and Method 2 cuts off small sections of the path because of decimal rounding off.

How can I resolve this? Is there a way to get precise bounds.

Answer (score -1):

i dont think there is a way, pass false to `path.computeBounds(figureLocationF, false);` and settle for an inexact measurement or true gives exact. if android exact is not good enough just calculate your own bounds. this is just convenience method. turn on google developer features in devleoper options "hardware accelerated rendering" and you can see highlights of your canvas redrawing.